# Two bundles using external - not finding modules

Tags: javascript, ember.js, build, browserify

I'm using [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) and having issues with things loading properly. I get the following error, which hardly makes sense since I'm using [aliases](https://github.com/AppGeo/ember-leaflet-scaffold/blob/calvin/package.json#L40).

> Cannot find module '/Users/knownasilya/sandbox/ember-leaflet-scaffold/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'

I'm unsure how `-x` works exactly, I tried the alias, I tried the bundle path, and I tried the paths for the libraries, but none work.

When I tried using the url of the libs bundle:

```
browserify -r jquery -r handlebars -r ember -r ember-data -r collapse -r leaflet > public/scripts/libs.js
browserify -x ./public/scripts/libs.js ./client/.index.js > ./public/scripts/application.js
```

I get `Cannot find module 'handlebars'` error. But if I add all of the libs (with `-x` for each with aliases) I get `Cannot find module 'QGCdlF'`.

I can't find any good examples, and maybe this is an issue with Ember itself, and how it requires `jquery` and `handlebars`.. The only time it works is when I do `"depends": ["jquery:jQuery", "handlebars:Handlebars"]`.. so make them globals..

Comment: Looks like we're having a similar issue, although via Gulp instead of command-line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121980/cannot-find-module-jquery-handling-globals-for-jquery-and-angularjs-in-bro

Comment: Have you checked out this issue? https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/issues/30

Comment: @RyanKimber no I haven't, thanks, I'll have a look. I've also tried it with gulp.