# "Cannot find module 'jquery'" - handling globals for JQuery and AngularJS in browserify with Gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify

I've been trying to create a project that utilizes `AngularJS`, `Browserify` and `Gulp` for an excellent developer experience, one that produces a distributable 'module' (in Angular parlance). The idea being to have a self-documented project, like `Angular Bootstrap`, that also produces a consumable distribution for use in another application.

We've had great results with `Gulp`, but we're having trouble with `browserify/browserify-shim`. Also, unfortunately, most of the examples out there either don't use gulp, or use `gulp-browserify`, which has been blacklisted/ended.

We're including `AngularJS` and `JQuery` from `Google CDN` as `<script>` tags and have declared `"angular" : "global:angular"` and `"jquery" : "global:$"` in our `browserify-shim` config in `package.json`, but we're getting `"cannot find module"` when we try to user `var angular = require('angular')` and `var $ = require('jquery')` inside of our browserified-code (once it runs in the browser).

I've created a sample project that distills this down close to the minimum.

[A sample repository of the code is available at](https://github.com/ryan-kimber/multi-browserify)

Once cloned, you would run `'npm install'`, then `'bower install'`, then `'gulp'` from the root of the `multi-browserify` folder to generate the files and run the test server.

With gulp running, you can access the live HTML at http://:4000/gulp.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm wondering if we've come across a bug/issue with the intersection of gulp, browserify, vinyl-source-stream, etc, or more likely, we just don't quite get it yet.

Comment: I've updated the test repository at https://github.com/ryan-kimber/multi-browserify to make it pretty barebones and I've provided a README.md that explains the issue, how to run the build and app and what the expected output should be.

Answer (score 2):

Is retrieving your dependencies from a CDN a requirement? If not, you could use npm for your dependencies and let browserify magic them up for you.

JQuery and Angular are available via npm, so using jquery as an example you could just declare it in your `package.json`, like so:

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.11.1"
  },
  ...
```

Alternatively, running `npm install <package> -s` from the directory containing your `package.json` will install the specified module and save it as a dependency in your `package.json` file.

Once you have installed this dependency (and any others you desire), you can go ahead and use them in your app.js as follows:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

$('<div>Hello World, I\'m using JQuery!</div>').appendTo('body');
```

Simple as that, and no need to use bower or browserify-shim - browserify will look through your node_modules folder and find them. I haven't tried this with angular (I had an issue trying to install it) - but it is available through [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular), so it should work.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question. The question very clearly describes a specific scenario and problem with it. This answer ignores the scenario completely.

Comment: I didn't ignore the scenario, but rather provided an alternative way of achieving what I believed to be their ultimate goal (being able to use JQuery) in a different way that they may not have considered. This approach would mean no need for browserify-shim, thus it would (albeit indirectly) solve their problem.

Comment: The whole point of the question is to use jQuery and Angular from a CDN, but be able to `require` them during development as usual. Thus, suggesting to bundle it with them rest of the project's JavaScript is totally avoiding the question.

Comment: I was unaware that browserify looked through npm package.json, this tip has just saved me a considerable amount of headache! +1

Answer (score 0):

```
# assuming you have installed jquery locally instead of globally
npm install jquery -s         # without -g flag
```

> instead of ***require(***"jquery"**)**, give relative path from source directory
>   ***require(***"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"**);**

Try the following:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');</script>
```

OR

```
<script>var $ = jQuery = require('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');</script>
```